# Im Having Issue Clearing and Refreshing The Page

Tags: java, jsp

A - Create a radio button list that has two choices :
o Provides
o None

B -Create two buttons namely, “Refresh” and “Clear”

C - You may want to create a scrollable container in this page too, which is initially empty and 
inactive} Show the result to the instructor before proceeding to next step.

Part 2: (55 Minutes) [80 points]

A - If Provides is selected and Refresh is pressed, the content of Provides table from FS database should be shown in a scrollable container;
B - If None is selected and Refresh is pressed, the content of the scrollable container is cleared. 
C - If Clear is pressed (no matter what is selected), the content of the scrollable container is cleared

Here is My Code: index.jsp file

Comment: <%-- 
Document   : index
Created on : 22-Oct-2015, 6:08:46 PM
Author     : AJ
--%>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Excercise 3</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>InClass Excercise 3</h1>

<div style="width:500px; height:500px; line-height:3em; overflow:auto; padding:5px;">

Comment: <form action="/Excersise3" method="get" name="Excersise3">

    <label><input type="radio" name="Provides" value="Provides" /> Provides<br /></label>
    <label><input type="radio" name="None" value="None" /> None<br /></label>      

        <input type="Submit" value="Refresh">
        <input type="Submit" value="Clear">

</form>

</div>



</body>
</html>

Comment: Don't post your code in comments since can't properly format it. Instead [edit] your question and put your code there (don't forget to wrap it in code section - `{}` button on editors menu).

Comment: So, do you have any question?